# D3 unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was trying to make a d3 example from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051 modified with my data. I use concepts similar to example. I didn't have problems with acquiring the data, but there's an unexpected identifier error.

```
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
.range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


d3.csv("datatest.csv", function(error, data) {
    var inflasiTahun = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "tahun"; });

    data.forEach(function(d) { 
        d.inflasi = inflasiTahun.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: parseFloat(d[name])}; }); 
    });


  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.tahun; }));
  x1.domain(inflasiTahun).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.inflasi, function(d) { return d.value; }); })

  svg.append("g") //this is the error
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Inflasi");

  var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.tahun) + ",0)"; });

  state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.inflasi; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

});

</script>
```

I dont know In the console, the unexpected identifier points to this:

```
svg.append("g") //this is the error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close the `y.domain([` with `]);` on the following line:

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.inflasi, function(d) { return d.value; }); })
```

Tools like JSLint and JSHint as well as proper indentation can help you in tracking down this kind of errors.